# Set size of a ToggleButton dynamicly

Tags: android

first of all sorry for my bad english :)
I'm new on programming for Android...
I'm trying to setup a view on runtime. I've created my own View class ( derived from AbsoluteView ) successfully, but if i try to resize the content of the view, nothing happens :(

Here is the full code i have wrote :

```
package com.CaliskanDevelopment.LottoGenerator;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CSelectNumbersLayout extends AbsoluteLayout 
{
private ToggleButton    m_clButton;

public CSelectNumbersLayout( Context    clContext )
{
    super( clContext );
    CreateButtons();
}

public CSelectNumbersLayout( Context        clContext,
                             AttributeSet   clAttributeSet )
{
    super( clContext, clAttributeSet );
    CreateButtons();
}

public CSelectNumbersLayout( Context        clContext,
                             AttributeSet   clAttributeSet,
                             int            i32DefStyle )
{
    super( clContext, clAttributeSet, i32DefStyle );
    CreateButtons();
}

private void CreateButtons()
{
    LayoutParams    clLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) generateDefaultLayoutParams();
    int             i32ButtonWidth = 10;
    int             i32ButtonHeight = 10;
    int             i32PosX = 0;
    int             i32PosY = 0;

    clLayoutParams.x = i32PosX;
    clLayoutParams.y = i32PosY;
    clLayoutParams.width = i32ButtonWidth;
    clLayoutParams.height = i32ButtonHeight;

    m_clButton = new ToggleButton( getContext() );
    m_clButton.setText( "setText" );
    m_clButton.setTextOn( "setTextOn" );
    m_clButton.setTextOff( "setTextOff" );
    m_clButton.setLayoutParams( clLayoutParams );

    this.addView( m_clButton );
}

protected void onSizeChanged( int   i32Width,
                              int   i32Height,
                              int   i32OldWidth,
                              int   i32OldHeight )
{
    int i;
    int i32ButtonWidth = ( i32Width / 7 );
    int i32ButtonHeight = ( i32Height / 7 );
    int i32PosX;
    int i32PosY;

    if ( i32ButtonWidth > i32ButtonHeight )
        i32ButtonWidth = i32ButtonHeight;
    else if ( i32ButtonHeight > i32ButtonWidth )
        i32ButtonHeight = i32ButtonWidth;

    i32PosX = ( i32Width / 2 ) - ( ( i32ButtonWidth * 7 ) / 2 );
    i32PosY = ( i32Height / 2 ) - ( ( i32ButtonHeight * 7 ) / 2 );

    LayoutParams    clLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) m_clButton.getLayoutParams();

    clLayoutParams.x = i32PosX;
    clLayoutParams.y = i32PosY;
    clLayoutParams.width = i32ButtonWidth;
    clLayoutParams.height = i32ButtonHeight;

    m_clButton.setLayoutParams( clLayoutParams );
    m_clButton.invalidate();

    this.invalidate();
}
}
```

I'm trying to resize the created buttons in function onSizeChanged, because i have readed that this is the first time where i know how big is my view. Calling things like

```
m_clButton.invalidate();
m_clButton.postInvalidate();
this.invalidate();
```

does not have the desired result.
The View is inside a Tab. If i click on the tab first time to show this Layout the Buttons are 10 x 10 ( as i created in the constructor ), i have debugged the Code, it runs over onSizeChanged but the buttons are not resized.
If i show another view and click at this tab again the buttons are resized.

I think the problem is to refresh the view in function onSizeChanged(), but how to do this ???

Thanks in advance...

Hasan Caliskan

Comment: Why are you creating your own view class? It doesn't look like you are doing anything other than laying out widgets on the screen.  You should just use a layout.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: That's right i'm not trying to layout a widget. This a Layout derived from AbsoluteLayout. I'm creating my own View class, because i want to create the buttons dynamicly where i know how big is my view. Or is there another way to overwrite this function to the existing class of AbsoluteLayout ??? I'm sorry but i'm very new to programming in Java ( Android ), I'm a developer in C++. :)